In theory, could an object like 'Oumuamua have been captured by a three-body interaction with the sun and planets?
I'm wondering, if it had entered on a trajectory that had caused it to fly by Jupiter, for example, in just the right way, could it have been captured by our Solar System? Or, was it simply moving too fast for that to have ever been a possibility?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOumuamua

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/58245/can-it-be-predicted-if-an-interstellar-object-will-get-bound-to-the-solar-system

The question that Mithron links to implies an answer:  There would have to be a strong interaction between the object and a planet:  essentially a reverse slingshot with the object losing, rather than gaining, orbital energy to a planet.  It's quite possible, but space is big and so such events are unlikely.

Maybe, but the probability is very low.
There are excellent answers at the recent related question, Can it be predicted if an Interstellar Object will get bound to the solar system by knowing its speed and direction? But I'll take this opportunity to give some actual numbers relevant to the trajectory of 'Oumuamua.
Horizons has a file for 'Oumuamua. From the body data page,

1I/'Oumuamua (A/2017 U1)
NOTE: This orbit solution includes non-gravitational perturbations [...] The behavior of these accelerations outside the observed data arc from 2017 October 14 to 2018 January 2 can only be assumed. Predictions outside this time interval, especially prior to October 2017, could be much more uncertain than reported here.

So please take the data in this answer with a grain of salt. ;)

We can determine whether a body is bound to the Sun by calculating its specific orbital energy, which is the sum of the body's kinetic and potential energies (relative to the Sun), per unit mass. The equation is
$$\varepsilon = \frac{v^2}{2} - \frac{\mu}{r}$$
where $\varepsilon$ is the specific orbital energy, $v$ is the body's speed (relative to the Sun), and $r$ is its distance from the centre of the Sun. $\mu$ is the gravitational parameter of the Sun.
Also,
$$\varepsilon = -\frac{\mu}{2a}$$
where $a$ is the semi-major axis  of the orbit; $a$ is negative for hyperbolic orbits.
In an isolated two body system, $\varepsilon$ is constant. If the body's orbit gets altered by interacting with a planet, then $\varepsilon$ can change.
If $\varepsilon$ is negative, the body is in a bound orbit. Otherwise, it's on an escape trajectory. If $\varepsilon$ is zero, the body's speed tends to the limit of zero as its distance approaches infinity. If $\varepsilon$ is positive, the body's speed tends to $v_{\infty} = \sqrt{2\varepsilon}$, the hyperbolic excess velocity.
Using the data from the Horizons page, we get
$\varepsilon \approx 348.432 \, \rm{(km/s)^2}$ and $v_{\infty}  \approx 26.405 \, \rm{km/s}$. So to capture 'Oumuamua we need to supply a fairly hefty amount of $\Delta v$. By comparison, the mean orbital speed of Earth is $\approx 29.78 \, \rm{km/s}$.
The specific orbital energy equation is closely related to the vis-viva equation,
$$v^2 = \mu\left(\frac2r - \frac1a\right)$$
(I have a derivation of the vis-viva equation at the end of this answer).
For a circular orbit, $r=a$, so $v=\sqrt{\mu/r}$. If a body at distance $r$ from the Sun has $v \ge \sqrt{2\mu/r}$, then its $\varepsilon \ge 0$, so it's unbound.
Wikipedia Gravity assist discusses the principles of the gravitational slingshot. Briefly, a slingshot can change a body's speed by upto twice the planet's speed, if the trajectories are in line. But that's extremely unlikely to occur for a body falling towards the Sun from the outer Solar System. It's much more likely for the body to cross the planet's orbit at roughly a right angle, and in that case, the maximum $\Delta v$ is roughly equal to the planet's speed. And in order for the body to be captured, its speed has to be reduced to less than $\sqrt{2}$ of the planet's speed.
The orbital radius of Jupiter is ~$5.2$ au, and its speed is ~$13.07 \, \rm{km/s}$. At that radius the speed of 'Oumuamua is ~$32.2 \, \rm{km/s}$, so an inline close Jupiter encounter could reduce its speed sufficiently, but a right-angle encounter wouldn't provide enough $\Delta v$.
At $1$ au, 'Oumuamua speed is up to ~$49.7 \, \rm{km/s}$, but Earth's speed is $29.78 \, \rm{km/s}$, as mentioned earlier. So a right-angle slingshot off Earth could work! We get even better results with Venus or Mercury.
Those estimates are based on treating the bodies as points.
After further thoughts and rough calculations, it looks like the asteroid would need to get closer than 1000 km to the planet centre to get sufficient deflection. Obviously, that's not possible. On the other hand, perhaps it can lose enough speed by atmospheric drag.

However, the probability of such an encounter is very small. Space is big, and a planet is very small compared to the perimeter of its orbit. For example, it takes Earth a year to traverse its orbit, but it covers a distance equal to its diameter in around 7 minutes. So even if an asteroid's trajectory crosses Earth's orbit, the probability that Earth will be in the vicinity at that time is ~(7 minutes) / (1 year).
But it's unlikely that an asteroid's trajectory will cross a planet's orbit. It could be falling towards the Sun from any angle. In the case of 'Oumuamua, its orbital plane is inclined to the ecliptic by ~$122.7417°$. It dropped into the Solar System from the north, whipped around the Sun, and headed back towards the north. Here's a diagram, produced using Horizons. In this diagram,  'Oumuamua is pink, approaching from the left, Jupiter is purple, Earth is blue. The grey plane is the ecliptic, and the pale grey line is the equinox direction. (The timestep is 50 days).

Here are some other plots produced using Horizons. Here's its distance and speed near the approach time, with a 1 day timestep.


Here's its specific angular momentum, relative to the Solar System barycentre (SSB). It actually picked up a little bit of orbital energy relative to the SSB by getting a slingshot off the Sun.

Here's its specific orbital energy, relative to the SSB.

And here's its specific orbital energy, relative to the Sun. Both of these calculations use the $\mu=GM$ value for the Sun from this JPL page.

Here's a plot of its distance from Earth near the time of its closest approach

Here's a close-up of the Sun, Earth, and 'Oumuamua from the 3D plot, from 2017-Aug-1 to 2017-Dec-1, with a 5 day timestep. Earth is moving anticlockwise, 'Oumuamua comes in from the upper right. This plot uses the rainbow mode, where the dot colour of the moving bodies is determined by the time, so dots with the same colour show the position at the same time. Note that this plot is rotated relative to the previous plot, in an attempt to make the 3D relationship more clear. But it's easier to see what's going on in the interactive 3D view.


Here's a little Python / Sage script that I used to do the energy and speed calculations.
And here's the 3D orbit script. See here for details of an earlier version of that script.
See
https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49267/16685 for a distance plotting script.

It appears that the Horizons ID# for 'Oumuamua has changed since I first posted this answer. I suspect that there's a bug due to the apostrophe in the name 'Oumuamua. Please see the body data page link near the top of this answer to get the current ID mumber. Or just use Oumuamua* instead of the ID number. That should work correctly in any of my Horizons scripts.

Great answer! In the first diagram, would it be possible to show which position of Earth matches the moment 'Oumuamua was (apparently) quite close to Earth's orbit?

@jcaron I've added another diagram that attempts to make that more clear, but it's hard to show it correctly in 2D. Please try the 3D orbit script, it should run in any Web browser, even on a smartphone.

Thanks, that was exactly the type of graph I had in mind. One can see that the blue dots of each trajectory are “relatively” close — at least Earth wasn’t on the other side of the Sun at that time. Also visible on the other graph you added, at 24.2 million km. How much closer would it have needed to be?

@jcaron 1 au is ~150 million km, so 24.2 million km isn't that close. To get significant deflection, it would have to get very close indeed. I haven't done the precise calculation, but I expect that it'd have to skim the atmosphere, at least.

Today the 'Oumuamua ID# is 50434520. This is really strange...
